# States computer wins everytime even though that's not the correct result in Android App

Tags: java, android

I have almost completed a tic tac toe app (player vs computer) in android but I have noticed a glitch in my game. No matter what the outcome is on the board, Computer always wins. So if player has three in a row or it's a draw, it still states Computer wins and I am not quite sure what bug I have put in my code to cause this. How can I get the correct outcomes for the game?

Below is the full code:

```
public class MainActivityPlayer1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button[][] buttons = new Button[3][3];

    private boolean playerOneMove = true;

    private int turnsCount;

    private int playerOnePoints;
    private int playerTwoPoints;

    private TextView textViewPlayerOne;
    private TextView textViewPlayerTwo;
    private TextView textViewPlayerOneTurn;
    private TextView textViewPlayerTwoTurn;

    int playerX = Color.parseColor("#e8e5e5");
    int playerO = Color.parseColor("#737374");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_player2);

        textViewPlayerOne = findViewById(R.id.textView_player1);
        textViewPlayerTwo = findViewById(R.id.textView_player2);
        textViewPlayerOneTurn = findViewById(R.id.textView_player1Turn);
        textViewPlayerTwoTurn = findViewById(R.id.textView_player2Turn);


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
                buttons[i][j] = findViewById(resID);
                buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);

                if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                    String btnState = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence(buttonID).toString();
                    if (btnState.equals("X")) {
                        buttons[i][j].setTextColor(playerX);
                    } else {
                        buttons[i][j].setTextColor(playerO);
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        Button buttonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
        buttonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetGame();
            }
        });

        Button buttonExit = findViewById(R.id.button_exit);
        buttonExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                backToMainActivity();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }

        if (playerOneMove) {
            ((Button) v).setText("X");
            ((Button) v).setTextColor(playerX);
            computerMove();
        }

        turnsCount++;

        if (checkGameIsWon()) {
            if (playerOneMove) {
                player1Wins();
            } else {
                player2Wins();
            }
        } else if (turnsCount == 9) {
            draw();
        } else {
            playerOneMove = !playerOneMove;
            switchPlayerTurn();
        }
    }

    private boolean computerMove() {
        playerOneMove = false;
        String[][] field = new String[3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
                if (field[i][j].equals("")) {
                    buttons[i][j].setText("O");
                    buttons[i][j].setTextColor(playerO);
                    turnsCount++;
                    switchPlayerTurn();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



    private boolean checkGameIsWon() {
        String[][] field = new String[3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                    && field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                    && !field[i][0].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[0][i].equals(field[1][i])
                    && field[0][i].equals(field[2][i])
                    && !field[0][i].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (field[0][0].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][0].equals(field[2][2])
                && !field[0][0].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        if (field[0][2].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][2].equals(field[2][0])
                && !field[0][2].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void player1Wins() {
        playerOnePoints++;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void player2Wins() {
        playerTwoPoints++;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Computer wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
        computerMove();
        playerOneMove = true;
        switchPlayerTurn();
    }

    private void draw() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        resetBoard();
        if (!playerOneMove){
            computerMove();
            turnsCount++;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void updatePointsText() {
        textViewPlayerOne.setText("Player 1:  " + playerOnePoints + " ");
        textViewPlayerTwo.setText("Computer: " + playerTwoPoints + " ");
    }

    private void resetBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                buttons[i][j].setText("");
            }
        }

        turnsCount = 0;
        switchPlayerTurn();
    }

    private void resetGame() {
        playerOnePoints = 0;
        playerTwoPoints = 0;
        turnsCount = 0;
        playerOneMove = true;
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt("turnsCount", turnsCount);
        outState.putInt("playerOnePoints", playerOnePoints);
        outState.putInt("playerTwoPoints", playerTwoPoints);
        outState.putBoolean("playerOneMove", playerOneMove);
        switchPlayerTurn();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                Button btn = buttons[i][j];
                outState.putCharSequence(buttonID, btn.getText());
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) { ;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        turnsCount = savedInstanceState.getInt("turnsCount");
        playerOnePoints = savedInstanceState.getInt("playerOnePoints");
        playerTwoPoints = savedInstanceState.getInt("playerTwoPoints");
        playerOneMove = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("playerOneMove");
        switchPlayerTurn();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                Button btn = buttons[i][j];
                savedInstanceState.putCharSequence(buttonID, btn.getText());

            }
        }

    }

    private void switchPlayerTurn(){
        if (playerOneMove){
            textViewPlayerOneTurn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textViewPlayerTwoTurn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            textViewPlayerOneTurn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            textViewPlayerTwoTurn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    private void backToMainActivity(){
        Intent intentMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentMainActivity);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are setting `playerOneMove = false;` (in `if (playerOneMove) {`) every time that player one is on turn by calling `computerMove()` and in that method you are immediately setting `playeOneMove = false;`.

If that's not the case please post `switchPlayerTurn()` method as well.

Also, I think that you should move your winning condition testings up, before `if(playerOneMove)`.

Example (I changed your condition, moved code for testing of winning conditions, created additional method...):

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }
                ((Button) v).setText("X");
                ((Button) v).setTextColor(playerX);
                playerOneMove = false;
                switchPlayerTurn();
                computerMove();
                playerOneMove = true;
                switchPlayerTurn();

        turnsCount++;
    }

    private boolean computerMove() {

        String[][] field = new String[3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
                if (field[i][j].equals("")) {
                    buttons[i][j].setText("O");
                    buttons[i][j].setTextColor(playerO);
                    turnsCount++;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



    private boolean checkGameIsWon() {
        String[][] field = new String[3][3];
        Boolean isDone = false.
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                    && field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                    && !field[i][0].equals("")) {
                isDone = true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[0][i].equals(field[1][i])
                    && field[0][i].equals(field[2][i])
                    && !field[0][i].equals("")) {
                isDone = true;
            }
        }

        if (field[0][0].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][0].equals(field[2][2])
                && !field[0][0].equals("")) {
            isDone = true;
        }

        if (field[0][2].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][2].equals(field[2][0])
                && !field[0][2].equals("")) {
            isDone = true;
        }
           if(isDone){
              if (playerOneMove) {
                  player1Wins();
                  return true;
              } else {
                  player2Wins();
                  return true;
              }
          }
          if (turnsCount == 9) {
              draw();
              return true;
          }
      }
    return false;
    }

    private void player1Wins() {
        playerOnePoints++;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void player2Wins() {
        playerTwoPoints++;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Computer wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
        computerMove();
        playerOneMove = true;
        switchPlayerTurn();
    }
```

Comment: Is it ok for me to ask to show me how it should look in the code please as I may be mistaken in the changes I am trying to make based on your answer?

Comment: @Merlin Uh, it's kinda hard because I don't see rest of your code (I don't have your full logic) but it should be something like code I added in answer.

Comment: @Merlin I edited code again, this should work. If it's not just turn on debugger and watch your variables step by step until you realize where is mistake. It's logical mistake, you should be able to resolve it easily with debugger if this doesn't work.

Comment: I will try edit 2 but I won't be able to do else{computerMove(),,, because it is under an onClick method. If I do n else then the computer does not make a move unless I click on a button twice

Comment: @Merlin I edited it again. This should work, I hope at least :')

Comment: Cool I'll give at go, I don't really want to put a isGameOver in there as I think is checkGameisWon is enough. I can try some debugging though to see what's up but the problem is it states the MainActivity1 needs to be in an intent filter which I have to figure out what that means

Comment: Can I ask in the mean time and call it last edit to try and update the answer so it does not contain Game is over? I'll try and see if I can get somewhere with the debugger

Comment: @Merlin I'm off PC right now. Will try to update it tho

Comment: Cool, I have got the debugger working so I will try to debug but if you don't see me place and update in a comment in next 45 mins then it means I have headed to work and not figured it out so if you don't mind looking at it if this occurs then it will be much appreciated :)

Comment: @Merlin I edited it again, I removed that method you didn't want.

Comment: II managed to debug it and fixed it. Thank you for your help again :)